# Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder' or one of its dependencies in class library project for unit testing

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, expression-encoder

I need to unit/integration test my web application using selenium so I need to record the screen. I have written it down in global setup and global tear down as:

```
    public void GlobalSetup()
            {
                SetupExtentReport();

                // Create a instance of ScreenCaptureJob
                PropertiesCollection.Recorder = new ScreenCaptureJob();

                // Specify the path & file name in which you want to save         
                PropertiesCollection.Recorder.OutputScreenCaptureFileName = @"C:\ScreenRecording.wmv";

                // Start the Screen Capture Job
                PropertiesCollection.Recorder.Start();

//remaining code
    }
```

and in tear down

```
    public void GlobalTearDown()
            {
                try
                {
                    //close extent reports
                    PropertiesCollection.ExtentReport.Flush();
                    PropertiesCollection.ExtentReport.Close();

                    //stop recorder
                    PropertiesCollection.Recorder.Stop();


                Console.WriteLine("Finished All Tests");
            }
}
```

But my test does not debug and this error comes in test explorer.

Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder version=4.0.0 ........ ' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I have been using Expression Encoder assembly referenced from installed folder.

Note: **My project is simple class library project**

This is a question which I viewed but it did not help me:
[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283043/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-expression-encoder)

I went through certain questions but in my case it's library project and cannot convert to 32-bit/64-bit since I am not on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change build platform target from "Any CPU" to "x86".